# Join on two tables with different relationships

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on a reporting feature for a Rails app where users contact people in offices. Each contact attempt belongs to an office. If the contact attempt is successful, then it also belongs to a person in the office.

The tricky part is when I try to filter the report by date range. I want to query for all of the offices that have been contacted in a date range, and all of the people in the offices contacted in that date range, but not people in those offices who weren't contacted in that range. In other words, if there are two people in the office, and one was contacted in the range and one wasn't, I only want to include that one contacted in that range.

I can easily get all of the contact attempts for an office in a particular date range:

```
Office.
  joins(:contact_attempts).
  where(contact_attempts: {created_at: @from_date..@to_date})
```

But then when I iterate through the people in the office, if one of them was contacted in the date range and the other wasn't, it will include both of them.

I attempted to filter out all of the uncontacted people like this:

```
Office.
  joins(:contact_attempts).
  where(contact_attempts: {created_at: @from_date..@to_date}).
  joins(people: :contact_attempts)
```

That doesn't actually change the results, though. So I tried:

```
Office.
  joins(:contact_attempts).
  where(contact_attempts: {created_at: @from_date..@to_date}).
  joins(people: :contact_attempts).
  where(people: {contact_attempts: {created_at: @from_date..@to_date}})
```

But that gives me `Unknown column 'people.contact_attempts'`.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `Person.joins(:contact_attempts).where(contact_attempts: {created_at: @from_date..@to_date})` should give the list of all contacted people, assuming the class relationships are set-up appropriately. See executable test case (which you can run with `ruby <filename>`) at https://github.com/prakashmurthy/executable_test_cases/blob/1264a86a22126fd1c644eacc9fa5bbe83a06625b/join_different_relationship.rb

Comment: Thanks @PrakashMurthy! The only thing is that I'm going to be iterating through the offices to get the people, not the people to get the offices. Your query will return the people, but how do I get the query to return the offices?